# Simplest way to print some message on the actual webpage by using JavaScript by using this specific code

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

So I already have the an html code file which is index.html and JavaScript code file which is app.js. They only teach me how to do console.log('') which prints things on Terminal, not the actual webpage I have. So what I want to do is making this code actually print some message on the actual webpage by changing the code as little as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>index.html</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <script src="app.js">

            </script>
      </body>


    </html>
```

And below is the JavaScript code

```
setTimeout(function(){

    //I want to print some message on the actual webpage. 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: `.appendTo('#yourId')`

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText = 'Some text';`

Comment: I'm not an expert in JS but I would suggest you to take a look at the popup, seems to be an easy way to print a message (unless you specifically want to print something on page where your focus is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the huge amount of solutions can be done by adding an ID attribute to any of your HTML tags, and then call this JS Code :

```
document.getElementById("your_tag_id").innerText = "your_text"
```

Basically, this will search for the given tag id in your html file, and add your text in. But avoid inserting HTML content with this method, prefer using DOM functions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: As I learned, it is not recommanded anymore to add HTML content by using `innerHTML`. Prefer creating a DOM element, and then append it to the chosen parent

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contents for a given element:

```
document.getElementById('ELEMENT').innerHTML = "Some text";
```

W3S has a basic tutorial for this:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Comment: Very poor reference [Better](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)